# Django user.save() fails on Column 'is_superuser' cannot be null

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-3.x, mysql-connector-python

I am trying to update user password using this code:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
u = User.objects.get(username='test')
u.set_password('test')
u.save()
```

but it falis everytime on these errors (without long messages from whole error message):

- `_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Column 'is_superuser' cannot be null`
- `mysql.connector.errors.IntegrityError: 1048 (23000): Column 'is_superuser' cannot be null`
- `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: Column 'is_superuser' cannot be null`
- `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'`

I am confused because this code is from official site so error is probably somewhere between django and mysql.

Thanks for advance

---

EDIT:

Code and complete error message:

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> user = User.objects.create_user('jj', 'lennon@thebeatles.com', 'johnpassword')
>>> user.save()
>>> u = User.objects.get(username='jj')
>>> print(u.is_superuser)
None
>>> u.save()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "home/mm/test/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 395, in cmd_query
    raw_as_string=raw_as_string)
_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Column 'is_superuser' cannot be null

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "home/mm/test/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/django/base.py", line 168, in _execute_wrapper
    return method(query, args)
  File "home/mm/test/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor_cext.py", line 266, in execute
    raw_as_string=self._raw_as_string)
  File "home/mm/test/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 398, in cmd_query
    sqlstate=exc.sqlstate)
mysql.connector.errors.IntegrityError: 1048 (23000): Column 'is_superuser' cannot be null

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "home/mm/test/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 99, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "home/mm/test/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "home/mm/test/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "home/mm/test/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "home/mm/test/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/django/base.py", line 218, in execute
    return self._execute_wrapper(self.cursor.execute, query, new_args)
  File "home/mm/test/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/django/base.py", line 174, in _execute_wrapper
    utils.IntegrityError(err.msg), sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "home/mm/test/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 683, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "home/mm/test/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/django/base.py", line 168, in _execute_wrapper
    return method(query, args)
  File "home/mm/test/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor_cext.py", line 266, in execute
    raw_as_string=self._raw_as_string)
  File "home/mm/test/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 398, in cmd_query
    sqlstate=exc.sqlstate)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: Column 'is_superuser' cannot be null

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "home/mm/test/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor_cext.py", line 606, in statement
    return self._executed.strip().decode('utf8')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "home/mm/test/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 66, in save
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "home/mm/test/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 741, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "home/mm/test/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 779, in save_base
    force_update, using, update_fields,
  File "home/mm/test/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 851, in _save_table
    forced_update)
  File "home/mm/test/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 900, in _do_update
    return filtered._update(values) > 0
  File "home/mm/test/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 760, in _update
    return query.get_compiler(self.db).execute_sql(CURSOR)
  File "home/mm/test/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1429, in execute_sql
    cursor = super().execute_sql(result_type)
  File "home/mm/test/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1100, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "home/mm/test/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 103, in execute
    sql = self.db.ops.last_executed_query(self.cursor, sql, params)
  File "home/mm/test/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/django/operations.py", line 127, in last_executed_query
    return force_text(cursor.statement, errors='replace')
  File "home/mm/test/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/django/base.py", line 230, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.cursor, attr)
  File "home/mm/test/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor_cext.py", line 608, in statement
    return self._executed.strip()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

Mysql row from `auth_user`:

```
| id | password                                                                       | last_login                 | is_superuser | username | first_name | last_name | email                 | is_staff | is_active | date_joined                |
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+--------------+----------+------------+-----------+-----------------------+----------+-----------+----------------------------+
| 16 | pbkdf2_sha256$150000$0gJWVPgCXeadjdfhdjslskfzurBD$yrWlrHM8foMnTm0MpDJ6yxv0/PI= | NULL                       |            0 | jj       |            |           | lennon@thebeatles.com |        0 |         1 | 2019-08-12 21:43:49.021511 |
```

Comment: Please include the full traceback (including the long messages. There's a reason why they're there. To help you diagnose and debug problems.). How did you add the "test" user to the database? It seems that the data in the database is not consistent with the django model. This is strange, since User is a built in model. You might have to fix it by either dropping all rows from the user table, or do a query such as `User.objects.filter(is_superuser=None).update(is_superuser=False)` or equivalent SQL.

Comment: @HåkenLid Added complete message and data from mysql.

Comment: This is strange. `User.objects.get(username='jj').is_superuser` should never be `None`. Both Django and MySql should prevent that from happening. The only way I can reproduce this is by explicitly setting `u.is_superuser = None` before saving. Could your mysql possibly have been messed up in some way?

Comment: If switching to postgres is an option, you might want to try that.

Comment: @HåkenLid I am using 'mysql.connector.django', should I try different mysql engine?

Comment: I don't use mysql myself, so I'm not the right person to ask.

Comment: @HåkenLid After switching to `django.db.backends.mysql` everything works well. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it looks like this error is beacuse of `mysql` engine `mysql.connector.django`. After installing `mysqlclient` using `pip install mysqlclient` and changing `ENGINE` inside `settings.py` to `django.db.backends.mysql` everything works well!

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the bug by using `'use_pure':True` in the database `OPTIONS`:

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
        'NAME': '<set>',
        'USER': '<set>',
        'PASSWORD': '<set>',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'use_pure':True
        },
    }
}
```

Thanks to Ciaran O'Sullivan, who found the workaround: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=92001

The solution also worked for me.

P.S. `use_pure` means that `mysql-connector` will use pure python connection, instead of its C extension (where I believe the bug is).
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-connecting.html

P.P.S The bug had appeared in version 8.0.13, which added python3.7 support: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-python/en/news-8-0-13.html